# conversão de estrutura de repetição(while) em C para assembly mips

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Suponha que `i` e `k`correspondam aos registradores `$s3` e `$s5`, e a base do *array* `save` esteja em `$s6`.

Qual o código *Assembly MIPS* correspondente a esse segmento de código *C*?

```
while( s a v e [ i ] == k )
i += 1 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [GNU Compiler Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) para gerar o código *assembly* equivalente ao programa escrito originalmente em linguagem `C`.

Assumindo que você está em uma arquitetura `x86`, você vai precisar de uma versão do `GCC` capaz de gerar código de máquina para a arquiteturas `MIPS` (*cross-compiler*), no caso em questão usaremos o [`mips64-linux-gnu-gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mips64-linux-gnu-gcc).

Instalando o `GCC` em *distros* RedHat (yum):

```
# yum install gcc-mips64-linux-gnu
```

Instalando o `GCC` em *distros* Debian (apt-get):

```
# apt-get install gcc-mips64-linux-gnu
```

Primeiramente implementamos um programa contendo o segmento de código em linguagem `C` que será analisado, vamos chamá-lo de `teste.c`:

```
int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 1;
    int save[ 8 ] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    while( save[ i ] == k )
        i += 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Para gerar o código em *assembly* para arquitetura `MIPS` equivalente ao programa `teste.c` listado acima:

```
$ mips64-linux-gnu-gcc -S teste.c -o teste.asm
```

Um arquivo de nome `teste.asm` será gerado:

```
    .file   1 "teste.c"
    .section .mdebug.abiN32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 1
    .abicalls
    .rdata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .word   8
    .word   7
    .word   6
    .word   5
    .word   4
    .word   3
    .word   2
    .word   1
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $fp,64,$31      # vars= 48, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x40000000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-64
    sd  $fp,56($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $0,0($fp)
    li  $2,1            # 0x1
    sw  $2,4($fp)
    lui $2,%hi(.LC0)
    addiu   $3,$2,%lo(.LC0)
    ldl $4,%lo(.LC0)($2)
    move    $5,$4
    ldr $5,7($3)
    addiu   $3,$2,%lo(.LC0)
    ldl $4,8($3)
    ldr $4,15($3)
    addiu   $3,$2,%lo(.LC0)
    ldl $6,16($3)
    move    $7,$6
    ldr $7,23($3)
    move    $3,$7
    addiu   $2,$2,%lo(.LC0)
    ldl $6,24($2)
    move    $7,$6
    ldr $7,31($2)
    move    $2,$7
    sd  $5,8($fp)
    sd  $4,16($fp)
    sd  $3,24($fp)
    sd  $2,32($fp)
    .option pic0
    j   .L2
    nop

    .option pic2
.L3:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,0($fp)
.L2:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    addu    $2,$fp,$2
    lw  $3,8($2)
    lw  $2,4($fp)
    beq $3,$2,.L3
    nop

    move    $2,$0
    move    $sp,$fp
    ld  $fp,56($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,64
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)"
```

Com uma breve análise do código *assembly* gerado, chegamos finalmente ao segmento de código equivalente ao laço `while`:

```
    j   .L2
    nop

    .option pic2
.L3:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1     # i += 1;
    sw  $2,0($fp)
.L2:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    addu    $2,$fp,$2
    lw  $3,8($2)
    lw  $2,4($fp)
    beq $3,$2,.L3       # while( save[ i ] == k )
    nop
```